# Unity: personagem anda de lado ao invés de andar de frente

Tags: c#, unity3d

Oi, estou com uma duvida na Unity3D 5!

O meu personagem, ao inves de se movimentar de frente, com WASD, ele se movimenta de lado. Meu script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;

        transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);
        transform.Translate(0, 0, z);
    }
}
```

Meu inputManager:

[image]

Não sei se importa, mas:

[image]

Comment: dê uma olhada aqui https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/translate-and-rotate

Comment: usei o mesmo script e continou o mesmo erro...

Comment: você só copiou e colou o código ou assistiu o video para entender o que está fazendo?

Comment: eu tinha copiado e colado, mas vi o video e nao adiantou nada tambem

Comment: O seu andar de lado... não é porque você construiu o objeto assim? Tipo colocou o canhão do tanque do lado dele e fez mais largo do que cumprido?

Answer (score 0):

Observe as setas de coordenadas, verifique se seu personagem está de frente para a posição X, e faça o seguinte:

```
var x = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;
transform.Translate(x,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Troque o `GetAxis` Vertical por Horizontal, assim:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;
        transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);
        transform.Translate(0, 0, z);
    }
}
```